# java serialization practice

Tags: java, serialization, kryo

I am reading across different methods/tools to serialize objects and I'm looking for an up-to-date suggestion for my application (as I can find a lot of similar question+answers from 2012, 2010, ...).

I need to write some java objects to disk. I would love to save disk space as these objects may contain a lot of data and I would love to do it rather fast.

So far it has been done with java standard serialization but the implementation is probably not very good (no explicit serialID set, ...). 
I read about the kryo library but I'm a bit afraid of using 3rd party libraries as I don't know how well they are maintained/ how common is their usage.
Or shall I just improve the use of the serializable interface and if yes, is there any good documentation on proper implementation?

Comment: Have a good look at the java.beans.XMLEncoder.

Comment: Another very fast library is Jackson 2, which is a json library.

Comment: XMLEncoder will blow up the file size for objects holding a lot of datapoints, no?

Comment: @July Why? Compared to what?

Comment: isn't every (sub-)object wrapped within tags? But I might be wrong in understanding how things are saved using the xml-encoder. compared to a file written via JOS for example...

Comment: @July Any DML encoder does that, not just this one.

Comment: @EJP: sure, but not any type of serialization.

Comment: There are are many java serialization libraries. Research them and find what suits you.

Answer (score 1):

This solution helps to save space on disk and is based on Java standard library

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file")));
oos.writeObject(obj);
...

ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("file")));
obj = ois.readObject();
...
```

Comment: Provided that the object is `Serializable`, of course. :-)

Comment: Sure, I dont think there is a solution of serializing of any object